# Syncfusion SfRangeSlider slider and label don't align properly when using autolayout constrains

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

Environment: Xamarin.iOS (NOT Xamarin.Forms), C#, Syncfusion components for Xamarin.iOS version 17.3.0.14

I am trying to use the Syncfusion `SfRangeSlider` to allow users select a value on a scale of 0-10.
I add the `SfRangeSlider` instances in the `ViewController`'s `ViewDidLoad` event and add autolayout constraints pinning slider's leading and training edges to the container and giving it a fixed height.

On initial load of the screen, the slider and the label that displays the notches and step values on the slider do not align properly (*see screenshot below*), the slider is noticeably shorter than the label. Once the slider is dragged a bit, the slider is then readjusted to match the width of the label.

#### Is there a way to keep the slider and the label to match each-other's width or is this a bug in the component?

## Sample of how the slider is added to the screen

```
public class SampleViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // create slider and add to View
        var contentSlider = new SfRangeSlider 
        {
            TickPlacement = SFTickPlacement.SFTickPlacementBottomRight,
            ValuePlacement = SFValuePlacement.SFValuePlacementBottomRight,
            SnapsTo = SFSnapsTo.SFSnapsToTicks,
            Maximum = 10,
            RangeEnd = 10,
            RangeStart = 0,
            StepFrequency = 1,
            TickFrequency = 1,
            TickColor = UIColor.White,
            ShowRange = false,
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        };
        View.AddSubview(contentSlider);

        // set up constraints for views
        View.AddConstraints(new NSLayoutConstraint[]{
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(contentSlider, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 0.0f),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(contentSlider, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1.0f, 20.0f),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(contentSlider, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1.0f, -20.0f),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(contentSlider, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 1f, 50f)
        });
    }
}
```

#### *NOTE: this `SampleViewController` is presented inside of a `UINavigationViewController`*

## Initial Screen Load screenshot

[image]

## First slider dragged a bit

[image]

Comment: It seems an issue of `SfRangeSlider` control when you use `autolayout`. Use a `frame` would work.

Comment: it sort of works using `frames` but it is a very subpar option that i really would rather not use, when you start managing things like shifting the UI up when the keyboard comes up so the user can see what they type into the textfield, then you have to start shifting the `y` positions on all these frames, it gets very messy, then handing multiple screen sizes and device types, that's one of the mian reasons autolayout is there, `Syncfusion` really needs to fix this, a professional component for iOS should absolutely work with `autolayout`, in my opinion. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. It should work with autolayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greetings from Syncfusion. We have checked the reported issue “Label of SfRangeSlider is not aligned properly while loading, it refreshes its layout only when changing the value” and were able to reproduce the same. We have already logged a defect report regarding on this and it can be tracked through our feedback portal below.

Feedback link: https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/10189/rangeslider-displays-the-last-additional-label-values

This fix will be included in our weekly release which is expected to be rolled out on November 26, 2019.

Comment: a link to a feedback ticket that is not viewable publicly or even by a signed in Syncfusion customer and user is not at all helpful

Comment: The reported issue's fix included in our 17.3.0.29 weekly Nuget release version which is rolled out today (November 26, 2019)

Please check and let us know if you have any other concern.

Comment: @DmitrySamuylov, please use our latest Nuget version of SfRangeSlider to resolve the issue